# How to return a result from the Blake2 crate in Rust?

Tags: hash, rust

I am struggling getting the hash of the passed file name using the `blake2` crate. From the documentation:

```rust
extern crate blake2;

use blake2::{Blake2b, Digest};
use std::env;
use std::fs;
use std::io::{self, Read};

const BUFFER_SIZE: usize = 1024;

fn print_result(sum: &[u8]) {
    for byte in sum {
        print!("{:02x}", byte);
    }
}

fn process<D: Digest + Default, R: Read>(reader: &mut R) {
    let mut sh = D::default();
    let mut buffer = [0u8; BUFFER_SIZE];
    loop {
        let n = match reader.read(&mut buffer) {
            Ok(n) => n,
            Err(_) => return,
        };
        sh.input(&buffer[..n]);
        if n == 0 || n < BUFFER_SIZE {
            break;
        }
    }
    print_result(&sh.result());
}

fn main() {
    let args = env::args();
    if args.len() > 1 {
        for path in args.skip(1) {
            if let Ok(mut file) = fs::File::open(&path) {
                process::<Blake2b, _>(&mut file);
            }
        }
    } else {
        process::<Blake2b, _>(&mut io::stdin());
    }
}
```

```
blake-test   $ cargo run hoge.txt
   Compiling blake-test v0.1.0 (/Users/hoge/blake-test)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.61s
     Running `target/debug/blake-test hoge.txt`
eefea9ae6b7fb678ed54e6d58d46aed9eae6d003f29419948cdb42a44a7016dee3eb566e7e95c68ac7587d5debd516a3b195eed0db84d72819e387d687fd06a6
```

It can successfully print the the `&[u8]` slice.

However, I want to receive/return the results instead of printing them.

Comment: It's very unclear what the problem is here; how have you tried to return it? Do you know how to return values in Rust?

Comment: @Shepmaster Sorry for the cunfusion. I would like to pass the value to a variable instead of just doing `print_result(&sh.result());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're returning a newly-created object, you have to return it as an *owned* value.

Borrowed references, such as `&[u8]` are temporary and can't exist by themselves, they're merely a views of data that has storage in an owned form elsewhere.

You can for example, call `.to_vec()` on the slice and return `Vec<u8>`.